# POST call to Keycloak to fetch access token works in postman, but not from AXIOS in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, backend, keycloak

I am trying to fetch the access token from Keycloak by making a call from Axios in NodeJs, but the call is failing. It is giving me a 'connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080'. But the same call when made through postman is succeeding. I am not able to figure the issue. Can anyone who know where I am going wrong please guide me through this?

This is my code in axios

```
var requestObject= querystring.stringify({
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    client_id: "demo-api",
    client_secret: <client-secret>,
    username: <user>,
    password: <password>
  });

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      "Accept":"*/*",
    }
  }
  try {
    const keycloakResponse = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url:'http://localhost:8080/realms/Demo-Realm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
      body: requestObject,
      headers: config.headers});
    res.send(keycloakResponse);
  } catch (error)
  {
    res.send(error);
  }
```

And this is the response I am getting

```
{
    "message": "connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080\n    at AxiosError.from (D:\\HEIDI\\myapp\\node_modules\\axios\\dist\\node\\axios.cjs:825:14)\n    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (D:\\HEIDI\\myapp\\node_modules\\axios\\dist\\node\\axios.cjs:2973:25)\n    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)\n    at eventHandlers.<computed> (D:\\HEIDI\\myapp\\node_modules\\follow-redirects\\index.js:14:24)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)\n    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:496:9)\n    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)\n    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)\n    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-Agent": "axios/1.3.4",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/realms/Demo-Realm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
        "body": "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=demo-api&client_secret=<client-secret>&username=<user>&password=<password>"
    },
    "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
    "status": null
}
```

But the call succeeds on postman

This is the request I make on postman

[image]

This is the response I get in postman

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong `client_secret` as same as Postman and
Don't necessary user's credential when you use `client_credentials` of `grant_type` in [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/18.0/authorization_services/)

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}' \
    "http://localhost:8080/realms/${realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

#### Demo

#1 Before you start Install Docker

```
https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/
```

#2 Start Keycloak

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.1 start-dev
```

#3 Login in to the Admin Console

```
http://localhost:8080/admin
```

Credential

```
Username: admin
Password: admin
```

#4 Create a realm

```
myrealm
```

#5 Create a client

```
myclient
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

#6 Copy the Client Secret

[image]

#7 Test Can Get Client Token

Set environment variables in terminal

The `CLIENT_SECRET` is should be copied from your Keycloak.

```
REALM_NAME=myrealm
CLIENT_ID=myclient
CLIENT_SECRET=gKz7hw0Pr92DbioSdDo5jfUz2LHLIoJw
```

Confirmed

```
echo $REALM_NAME
echo $CLIENT_ID
echo $CLIENT_SECRET
```

[image]

Get token by `curl`

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--silent \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id='$CLIENT_ID \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret='$CLIENT_SECRET | jq -r '.access_token'
```

[image]

#7 Get Token by node.js

Install Dependencies

```
npm install axios querystring
```

Remember copy/replace your `client secret`

save this code as `get-token.js`

```
const axios = require('axios')
const querystring = require('querystring');

const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const requestObject= querystring.stringify({
            grant_type: "client_credentials",
            client_id: "myclient",
            client_secret: "gKz7hw0Pr92DbioSdDo5jfUz2LHLIoJw"
        });
        const config = {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              "Accept":"*/*",
            }
        }
        const resp = await axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
            data: requestObject,
            headers: config.headers});

        return Promise.resolve(resp.data)
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
}

getToken()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
    });
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed response. I can confirm that I am giving the correct client_secret. I had just hid the client_secret while posting the question. I also tried the same thing that you had done, but I am still getting the same error. Do you know what the issue is?

Comment: @AjayUmakanth, you use wrong parameter in post call. It needs to change from `body: requestObject` to `data: requestObject`. I updated your coding style in my answers. Can you vote me? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Bench Vue, thanks for the quick response. Even when I changed it to data: requestObject, I am still getting the same error. I had actually copied your entire code that you had sent (and updated it with my client-id), but I unfortunately got the same error :-(

Comment: Which Keycloak version using? I will update step by step my answer at Tonight.

Comment: I am using version 21

Comment: @AjayUmakanth, I updated with v21.0.1 , Can you try it?